# RSA Algorithm (private key calculation) in bash

Tags: bash, key, rsa, private

Looking for help on how to calculate the RSA secret key in a bash script 'd' when p, q & e are given.

Although I know this query has come up before, all I seem to find is theoretical advice on the calculation of the RSA private key when p, q & e are given.

I am trying to put a calculation in a bash script together and so would really like some
explanation on the calculations possible in bash (with expr or bc)

I found a site that basically advised the following; 
(with 't' being the totient of p*q, or rather the totient of 'n')

`d=$(echo "((2 * $t) + 1) / $e" | bc)`

But that only seems to work on that specific case and did not provide the correct output when trying on different cases.

Any help on how I could write a bash formula for this calculation ?

Comment: I have some questins on that: 1. Is this question actually about "How to perform mathematical calculations in bash"?   2. Why are you considering to write an RSA algorithm on your own, why not using openSSL etc. which already does the job perfectly for you?

Comment: If there is a program that can tell me what the 'd' value would be given the information on p, q & e, then thats perfectly fine I suppose. But I would also like to understand how it I can actually calculate the value in a bash script.

Comment: There are more things involved in modern encryption RSA based algorithms than the simple "wikipedia" exaples provide. You definetly should not rely on a simple bash script to encrypt/decrypt sensitive data, unless you are playing around. Just google "openssl" and "rsa encryption" to learn how to use openssl if you need to encrypt sensitive data

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified, this is not for any personal project, it is for a solution of an online challenge (challenge now open). Hence my queries here.. I understand your responses, but it's not what I am looking for. I am looking for an example code with which I would be able to calculate 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

From the defition of RSA

|e*d| = 1 (mod fi(p*q))

where fi(n) is the Euler function

So you need to calculate the inversion of e in this modulo. Don't forget to check if GCD(e,fi(p*q))=1 or you may not find an inversion of e in the given modulo.

You can achieve this by using Extended Euclidean algorithm. There is a lot of pseudocodes on the web. Do you need more help?